# Problems using iPad image on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a universal app, and I'm trying to use my iPad images for the iPhone6 and 6+ to save space in the binary. I do the following line:

```
logoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo@2x~ipad"];
```

and get:

> CUICatalog: Can't find rendition for name: Logo@2x~ipad scale factor:
>   2 device idiom: 1 device subtype: 568

and the `UIImageView` is blank of course. Has anyone run into this before? I've seen a couple of questions on this where CocoaPods was the problem, but I'm not using CocoaPods so it must be something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone from Apple on the dev forums told me that this just isn't possible to do and that I'll have to rename my file if I want to use it for both the iPad and iPhone6 / 6+.

Answer (score 0):

Error message you've got says that you are using assets catalog and it can't find correct image for you.

There are two possible solutions:

- Add all required images to your image set. Consider using size classes.
- Don't use assets catalog. Then you will have full freedom in loading images you like in appropriate case.

I'd recommend to stay with assets catalog for all or most images. Is your logo is really so large? If it is really so large and you can't avoid image duplicates in your assets catalog then use only this one "image set" separately outside assets catalog.

Comment: Someone on the Apple forum told me this isn't possible to do, so just need to rename the images. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: He lied ;) You always can load image from outside assets catalog and for sure you can add all required images to your assets catalog and use them with size classes if appropriate.

Comment: I had tried what you said and deleted my assets catalog file and still got the same result. You just can't load a specific iPad image with ~ipad directly using imageNamed:

Comment: Hmm, I didn't check with "~ipad" and didn't think this suffix is important for you. Anyway, you still can load that image. You should just use imageWithContentsOfFile for such specific files and keep in mind that loaded images won't be cached automatically.